# Basic SVM issues with e1071: test error rate doesn't match up with tune's results

Tags: r, machine-learning, svm, libsvm

This seems like a very basic question but I can't seem to find the answer anywhere. I'm new to SVMs and ML in general and am trying to do a few simple exercises but the results don't seem to match up. I'm using e1071 with R and have been going through *An Introduction to Statistical Learning* by James, Witten, Hastie, and Tibshirani.

My question: why is it that when I use predict I don't seem to have any classification errors and yet the results of the tune function indicate a non-zero error rate?
My code (I'm looking at three classes):

```
set.seed(4)
dat <- data.frame(pop = rnorm(900, c(0,3,6), 1), strat = factor(rep(c(0,1,2), times=300)))
ind <- sample(1:900)
train <- dat[ind[1:600],]
test <- dat[ind[601:900],]

tune1 <- tune(svm, train.x=train[,1], train.y=train[,2], kernel="radial", ranges=list(cost=10^(-1:2), gamma=c(.5,1,2)))
svm.tuned <- svm(train[,2]~., data=train, kernel = "radial",  cost=10, gamma=1) # I just entered the optimal cost and gamma values returned by tune
test.pred <- predict(svm.tuned, newdata=data.frame(pop=test[,1],strat=test[,2]))
```

So when I look at test.pred I see that every value matches up with the true class labels. Yet when I tuned the model it gave an error rate of around 0.06, and either way a test error rate of 0 seems absurd for nonseparable data (unless I'm wrong about this not being separable?). Any clarification would be tremendously helpful.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`tune` functions performs 10 cross validation. It **randomly** splits your training data into 10 parts and then iteratively:

- selects each of them and call it "validation set"
- select remaining 9 and call them "training set"
- it trains the SVM with given parameters on the training set, and checks how well it works on validation set
- computes mean error across these 10 "folds"

The information from the "tune" function is this mean error. Once the best parameters are chosen, you are training your model on the **whole** set, which is exactly 1/9 bigger then the ones used for tuning. As a result, in your particular case (it does not happen often) - you get the classifier which perfectly predicts your "test" set, and some of the smaller ones trianed while tuning - made a small mistake(s) - this is why you get the information regarding different errors.

**UPDATE**

It seems, that you are actually also training your model on both **inputs** and **labels**.. Look at your

```
svm.tuned$SV
```

variable, which holds the support vectors.

To train svm, simply run

```
svm(x,y,kernel="...",...)
```

for example

```
svm(train$pop, train$strat, kernel="linear" )
```

which results in some missclassifications (as expected, as linear kernel cannot perfectly separate such data).

Or using your notation

```
svm.tuned <- svm(strat~., data=train, kernel = "radial",  cost=10, gamma=1)
```

note that you should use the name of the frame column **strat**, not the index.

Comment: So even though these data are rather nonseparable this model was still able to perfectly classify all of them? That just seems a little hard to believe. Regardless, thanks for clearing up why CV error rates seem to always be a bit bigger than overall training error rate.

Comment: What do you mean by nonseparable? You are using gaussian kernel, which with correct parameters will separate **any consistent dataset** (consistent = there are no two exactly same points with different labels). This is a consequence of infinitely dimensional feature space.

Comment: Thank you so much! That update has solved it. Also thanks for defining a consistent dataset, I hadn't heard that term before.